# Memcached connecting but not working using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, memcached

I have just installed **memcached** on my **vmware debian server** and the nodejs script looks like this:

```
var Memcached   = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('127.0.0.1:11211');

memcached.set('foo', 'dass');
var data = memcached.get('foo');

console.log(data);
console.log(memcached.stats);
```

For the first `console.log` I get this: `undefined`

For the second `console.log` I get this: `[Function: bowlofcurry]`

*Not sure what am doing wrong here :(* anyone?

The module: https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached

Comment: *what am doing wrong here* - thinking in 'sync' mode when dealing with Node. One obvious example is that `mc.get` function does not return a result immediately, but instead activates a callback (sent as param) when the result as ready.

Comment: If Sync method is available, I want to use it then. It is easier for me to understand a test code.

Answer (score 1):

Data will come in callback:

```
memcached.get('foo', function (err, data)
{            
    console.log(data);
});
```

Full documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached).